# Count unique values in csv column without pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm using python3 and I want to count unique values in column without pandas

For example if I have this csv:

```
Name,Surname,PCName,File_Name
Max,Petrov,wrs123,test2.csv
Ivan,Ivanov,wrs321,test2.csv
Vasily,Sidorov,wrs223,test3.csv
Alex,Dmitriev,wrs331,test3.csv
Alexey,Dmitriev,wrs333,test3.csv
```

With pandas I've got this code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('C:/tmp/test.csv', index_col=0)
print(df["Surname"].value_counts())
```

And this result:

```
Dmitriev    2
Petrov      1
Ivanov      1
Sidorov     1
```

Comment: : Pandas is specifically designed for data analysis purpose. Iterating through the file data line by line will be too much costly operation via looping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, you can use [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module to read and process your data:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

counter = defaultdict(int)
with open('test.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        counter[row['Surname']] += 1
        
print(dict(counter))
```

**Output:**

```
{'Petrov': 1, 'Ivanov': 1, 'Sidorov': 1, 'Dmitriev': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `pandas` for this. It makes life **simpler** and **easier**

**Code :**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("/content/sample_data/abc.csv")
get_count = df.pivot_table(columns=['Surname'], aggfunc='size')
print(get_count)
```

**Output :**

[image: Output]